# iOS UILocalNotification every Monday

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Does someone know how I can make a UILocalNotification set on everymonday 19:00.
Then when that time has come, I need to check my .plist file from my website, if I put the string in the .plist time to YES then the UILocalNotification should show up. 
Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create UILocalNotification that will be repeated weekly:

```
notification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitWeekday
```

But you won't be able to run a custom code when it occurs. It depends if user will open your app or not. If user ignores notification - nothing happens - no way to run code.

If user opens notification you can detect it:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

     UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (localNotif) 
    {
        //TODO: handle
    }
```

}